# Moq partial class like in Rhino Mocks

Tags: unit-testing, moq

Hi I'm new to Mocking.

I have a class:

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual void Register() {
        ...
        Warrant();
    }

    public virtual void Warrant() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I was wanting to test that `Register` calls `Warrant`. Using RhinoMocks I came up with:

```
[Test]
public void RhinoCarTest() {
    var mocks = new Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository();
    var car = mocks.PartialMock<Car>();

    mocks.ReplayAll();

    car.Stub(x => x.Warrant());

    car.Register();

    car.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Warrant());
}
```

I'm not even sure if this is correct but it seemed to do the job.  I was wanting to do the same thing in Moq. I couldn't seem to find a partial Moq.

What I came up with was:

```
[Test]
public void MoqCarTest() {
    var car = new Mock<Car>();

    car.Setup(x => x.Warrant());

    car.Object.Register();

    car.Verify(x => x.Warrant());
}
```

This doesn't even work though. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial classes in Rhino.Mocks will call the base class methods unless you set up a Mock and/or stub.  By default, Moq will only call base class methods if you create the mock to specifically do that.  Here's an example that will work for your example:

```
var car = new Mock<Car> {CallBase = true};
car.Object.Register();
car.Verify(c => c.Warrant(), Times.Once());
```

However, I would try and avoid this approach (verifying that a specific method was called).  Instead, your test should simply ensure that the correct "work" was done after calling the method.  How that work gets done is a private implementation of the method.

If you write tests that ensure certain methods are called, your tests can become more brittle over time -- especially as you refactor for performance or other issues.

Comment: Hi Patrick Steele, thanks for your answer. So would this be correct to say you Stub out the Register method and make it so the stub returns what you want in the test. Then you just test the functionality is correct. Another thing is if your saying you shouldn't check methods have been called are you saying that ideally you shouldn't be using Verify at all?

Comment: If the Register method is what you want to test, you'd stub out the Warrant method so that any bugs in there won't affect your unit test for Register.  Then, you write a separate unit test for Warrant.  I use Verify to make sure methods are called on certain objects (usually dependencies). Example: if I have a class that should save data to a database, I verify that during my call to "Update", that my mock IReporitory's "Save" method was called. Likewise, I can make sure it ISN'T called when it shouldn't be.